# setting a parameter name in jquery Ajax request for json POST data

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I'm sending a POST request with json like this:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "myurl.htm",
     contentType: "application/json",
     data: '{"val1":"something","stuff":[{"val1":"value1","data":"Someone"}]}',
     dataType: "json"
});
```

When I look at this requet from `Network` its passing the following payload

`{"val1":"something","stuff":[{"val1":"value1","data":"Someone"}]}`

However, I want the request load to be:

`mydata: {"val1":"something","stuff":[{"val1":"value1","data":"Someone"}]}`

Because my controller is accepting the following:

```
 @RequestMapping(headers ={"Accept=application/json"},value="/myurl.htm", method= RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView mymethod(
      @RequestParam(value="mydata", required=false) String mydata {
  logger.info(mydata);
}
```

So I need a way to simply give a parameter name to the json data I'm sending to the server as POST request.

Comment: try to use `data:'mydate='+json_content`?  It will send it like a post parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this? Since json is just a string and you are posting data this should work.

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "myurl.htm",
     contentType: "application/json",
     data: 'mydata={"val1":"something","stuff":[{"val1":"value1","data":"Someone"}]}',
     dataType: "text"
});
```

Comment: no, my controller doesn't read `mydata` as a parameter if i do that

Comment: change the dataType:"json" to dataType:"text". You are not requesting Json, You are sending it. Sorry I didn't see it... I changed it in my answer.